# Details about root causes of bugs

Tags: defect-tracking

I'm working on root causes of defects, and I'm end up with following list, which is generally accepted. Even the list is everywhere on the internet, there's no details about the items. Any expertise or reference about the following items are welcome.

- Incomplete or erroneous specification (IES)
- Misinterpretation of customer communication (MCC)
- Intentional deviation from specifications (IDS)
- Violations of programming standards (VPS)
- Error in data representations (EDR)
- Inconsistent component interface (ICI)
- Error in design logic (EDL)
- Incomplete or erroneous testing (IET)
- Inaccurate or inconsistent documentation (IID)
- Error in programming language translation of design (PLT)
- Ambiguous or inconsistent human/computer interface (HCI)
- Miscellaneous (MIS)

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Turcia. What's the purpose of creating such a list?

Comment: @dzieciou, To collect metrics about bug causes and strengthen our weak points. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago, Gregory Pope published even a [longer list of root causes of bugs](http://silverbuckshot.net/Problem%20List) together with an extensive list of techniques to either detect or prevent those problems.

All the material has been presented during ALM 2011 Keynote and [recorded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhbLV16z4KE), together with [slides](http://www.stickyminds.com/sites/default/files/presentation/file/2013/11ADPER_TK3.pdf), if you have less time, but I really recommend listening to the recorded presentation because it has lots of real life examples.